How to use Postgresql json_set in conjuction with pgsql-http
I have a database trigger function like this:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.webhook()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
    BEGIN
        PERFORM status FROM 
http_post('https://example.com/receiver', jsonb_set(jsonb_build_object('action',TG_OP,'table',TG_TABLE_NAME),'{value}',
to_jsonb(NEW.*)));
        RETURN NULL;
    END;
$function$
;

But I get now new field "value" inside my json. What is wrong with my function?
What I'm trying to achieve is to get
{
"table": "issues",
"action": "UPDATE",
"value": ####
}

in my request body, with #### containing the changed record.
It works with
PERFORM status FROM 
http_post('https://example.com/receiver', to_jsonb(NEW.*));

but I want to have the action and table too.

Why are you trying to unpack NEW before conversion? You should be able to to_jsonb(NEW) just fine. What you're showing works ok if you're trying to nest the new record under the value key: demo. If you're trying to get a JSON version of that record, with table and action added into it, flip the arguments: don't add the record to a JSON with the pair of keys but instead use jsonb_set or jsonb_insert twice to add them to the record. Or, concatenate || these together

The problem is less inside json_set, as I assumed in the question, it is more in the conjunction with http_post() from pgsql-http. If I cast the jsonb object to text and change that http_post() call to this:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.webhook()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
    BEGIN
        PERFORM status FROM 
        http_post('https://automate.nrkt.enerkite.com/webhook-test/redmine', 
            jsonb_build_object( 'action',TG_OP,
                                'table',TG_TABLE_NAME,
                                'value',to_jsonb(NEW.*))::text,
                                'application/json');
        RETURN NULL;
    END;
$function$
;

it works.
Thank You all for helping. Zegarek, you pointed me in the right direction by You debug mechanism, which showed, taht my problem was not where I thought.

You can get the required structure with something like this:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.webhook()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
    BEGIN
        PERFORM status FROM 
        http_post('https://example.com/receiver', 
            jsonb_build_object(
                'action', TG_OP,
                'table', TG_TABLE_NAME,
                'value', to_jsonb(NEW.*)
            )
        );
        RETURN NULL;
    END;
$function$
;

jsonb_build_object constructs the entire JSON object in one go.

Thank you very much. I (think I) tried that before. Strangely, I stll get only {"table": "issues","action": "UPDATE"} in my body. With replacing to_jsonb(NEW.*) with hello I get {"table": "issues","value": "hello","action": "UPDATE"} as expected.

Same with 'value', jsonb_build_object('val1', 'hello'), so independet of NEW.*. somehow, a jsonb data type seems not to be acceptend as a value of a jsonb object. Same with 'value', json_build_object('val1', 'hello'), value just doesn't appear in the body.

What you're showing works ok if you're trying to nest the new record under the value key:
demo at db<>fiddle
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.webhook()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
    BEGIN
        create table debug_ as 
        select 'https://example.com/receiver'
              , jsonb_set(jsonb_build_object( 'action',TG_OP
                                             ,'table',TG_TABLE_NAME)
                          ,'{value}',to_jsonb(NEW.*));
        RETURN NULL;
    END;
$function$
;
create table b(i int default 5);
create trigger trg before insert on b
for each row execute function webhook();
insert into b select;
table debug_;




?column?
jsonb_set




https://example.com/receiver
{"table": "b", "value": {"i": 5}, "action": "INSERT"}



If you're trying to get a JSON version of that record, with table and action added into it, flip the arguments: don't add the record to a JSON with the pair of keys but instead use jsonb_set() or jsonb_insert() twice to add them to the record.
Or, concatenate || these together (that's a dedicated operator for merging jsonb's, not to be confused with text concatenation):
demo at db<>fiddle
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.webhook()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
    BEGIN
        create table debug_ as 
        select 'https://example.com/receiver'
              , jsonb_build_object( 'action',TG_OP
                                   ,'table',TG_TABLE_NAME)
                || to_jsonb(NEW) as payload;
        RETURN NULL;
    END;
$function$
;
create table b(i int default 5);
create trigger trg before insert on b
for each row execute function webhook();
insert into b select;
table debug_;




?column?
payload




https://example.com/receiver
{"i": 5, "table": "b", "action": "INSERT"}



You should be able to to_jsonb(NEW) without unpacking NEW.*.

Thank You! The second variant I already had working, but I want to have it nested under the value key. So, as far as I can see, Your first example is identical to my question posting in terms of jsonb_set function. And this leads to an missing value in my body. So, since it works locally with your example, the error must be somewhere down the stream towards my webhook receiver?

What somehow works is casting to text: 'value',to_jsonb(NEW.*)::text)); This way I get the value, but the value of value ist urlencoded, not a real json entry. But at least something.

I only get the empty value key if NEW happens to be empty. What 's the target table DDL, what types build up a row of that table that you expect under NEW? How do you attach the trigger function (what's the trigger before/instead/after action, is it a row or statement-leve trigger, is it on update/insert/delete)? It would be easier if you showed exactly how you test these, end-to-end, if you are allowed to share or have the time to prepare a full MRE.
